# fix Zurb Foundation Grid with different height

Tags: jquery, css, zurb-foundation

Foundation's Grid break when there are "uneven" hight to each columns, especially if all inside one row.  as you can see from the Jsfiddle example below.

I don't want to use equalizer since it cause real performance issue for my site.

I don't know how many column will be produce by my PHP code so I can't really put it in separate row.

any one have a solution to this?

[edit] currently my solution involve predefine max col per row, and use a counter to end and start a new row.  but it's not very responsive.

https://jsfiddle.net/eq2q4rc4/

```js
var col = '<div class="small-3 columns">content</div>', 
  row = $('.row'), 
    colCount = 30,
    i = 0, 
    maxRange = 1000; 
    
    for(i=0; i<colCount; i++) {
     row.append(col);
    }
    
    $('.columns').each(
     function() {
       $(this).css({'height':Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1)});
      }
    );
```

```css
.columns {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.3.1/css/foundation.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">

</div>
```

Comment: Have you considered using their flex box implementation? http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/flex-grid.html#vertical-alignment-of-child-columns-individually-

Comment: I knew flex box is there, but a bit too scare as how it work in real life (compatibility).  you have experience with it?

Comment: Do you have a list of browsers you need to support? http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox is a helpful resource in case you're not aware. We support IE11 & evergreen browsers. Foundation's Flex grid works really well in cases like yours.

Comment: I guess I will have a go with flex grid, and figure out IE10 later.

Comment: Flex Grid in Foundation 6 claims to support IE10+. http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/flex-grid.html#browser-support

Your mileage may vary though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing Foundation to use the flex grid `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.3.1/css/foundation-flex.min.css` with your code should get you better results. https://jsfiddle.net/k07wktgL/1/

```js
var col = '<div class="small-3 columns">content</div>', 
    row = $('.row'), 
    colCount = 30,
    i = 0, 
    maxRange = 1000; 
    
for(i=0; i<colCount; i++) {
    row.append(col);
}
    
$('.columns').each(
        function() {
        $(this).css({'height':Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1)});
    }
);
```

```css
.columns {
   background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.3.1/css/foundation-flex.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row"></div>
```